# jQuery .live() and .each() with AJAX polling

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, each

I have a simple function that goes through the page and adds a CSS class to each element that matches, using `.each()`. I'm also constantly updating the page with AJAX, and after the first AJAX update that changes things, the function no longer applies.

Code:

```
$("div.col-conversation span.label-sticky").each(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('stickyhighlight');
});
```

I understand why it doesn't work after the first AJAX event and went to try to use `.live()` or `.delegate()` but it doesn't appear that you can bind things that aren't events (i.e. you can only bind to click, hover etc.) using this method, so `.each()` isn't going to work.

Is there a simple way to execute this function without including it in the AJAX success callback and without using a plugin like livequery, which is probably overkill?

Comment: When do you call the function that calls `.each`?

Comment: [`live` is dead as it can be](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed)...

Comment: I think @ExplosionPills is on the right track. You're not calling the function to add the classes after new content has been loaded to the page.

Comment: To answer the first question... before it was called on `$(document).ready()`. I know `live()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
$('body').on('mychange','div.col-conversation span.label-sticky',function () {
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('stickyhighlight');
});
```

Add this to your ajax success function:

```
$('body').trigger('mychange');
```

**OR if you really don't want to (or can't) modify the ajax success function:**

```
setInterval(function() {
   $('div.col-conversation span.label-sticky').each(function () {
       $(this).closest('li').addClass('stickyhighlight');
   });
},100);
```

Comment: in order for this to work, wouldn't i technically have to use both functions, one for the initial page load and the one you wrote to keep the item highlighted after an AJAX event?

Comment: though adding the `.trigger()` to the ajax success function isn't a whole lot better than just copy/pasting the original function into the ajax success function? I guess it is.

Answer (score 1):

What's probably better than attaching an event handler for each matching item is to attach an event with jQuery.on() with a selector parameter. It allows you to do something like:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.yourClass', function(event){ doStuff(); });
```

with

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="yourClass">...</span>
    <div class="yourClass">...</div>
    <anything class="yourClass">...</anything>
</div>
```

This means that only one event listener needs to be active instead of one event per item with the class. It also means that if you add items to the container, you won't need to update the listener. It's better performance and easier to deal with.

Check [jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more about .on().

Comment: looks like I do need to look into `on()`